# Android: Listview perde informação/estado quando se coloca a app em background

Tags: android, mobile, app

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma aplicação android que preenche uma listview com determinadas informações, sendo que nesta listview existe uma validação que alera a cor da linha consoante a prioridade de cada registo (ex. amarelo = 1, verde = 2, etc...).

O que acontece e que quando a listview é carregada inicialmente as corres aparecem corretamente em cada um dos registos, no entanto se eu efetuar diversos scrool's ao longo da listview esta vai perdendo estas prioridades e os registos acabam por ficar todos de uma só cor. O mesmo acontece se eu colocar a app em background e quando volto a colocar em primeiro plano os registos passam a aparecer todos da mesma cor.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que se possa estar a passar?

Atenciosamente
Nuno Santos...

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho um projeto onde uso uma lista e no adapter informo quais as cores elas devem ser identificadas, inclusive a cor original de quando a lista começa sem nenhuma alteração.

Exemplo, no adapter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]